# using system.reflection to list a class fileds

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

i need to get a list to store all fields - values in a class

the class is just a few of public `const string` variables as i pasted below.

```
public class HTDB_Cols
{
    public class TblCustomers
    {
        public const string CustID  = "custID",
               Name  = "name",
         CustType  = "custType",
         AddDate  = "addDate",
         Address  = "address",
         City  = "city",
         Phone  = "phone",
         Cell  = "cell";
    }
}
```

this is a method that returns a list of strings that enables me to have a list of strings representing all my tables columns names , though somthing is not working with this code as i get an error

" *Non-static field requires a target*".

```
public class GetClassFields
{

        public static List<string> AsList(string TableName)
        {


                    return typeof(HTDB_Cols).GetNestedTypes()
                    .First(t => String.Compare(t.Name, TableName, true) == 0)
                    .GetFields()
                    .Select(f => f.GetValue(null) as string)
                    .ToList();

        }
}
```

trying to use it as follows :

```
foreach (string tblCol in RobCS_212a.Utils.Reflct.GetClassFields.AsList      (DBSchema.HTDB_Tables.TblCustomers))
{
    Response.Write(string.Concat(tblCol, "<br />"));
}
```

Field 'tbName' defined on type 'DBSchema.HTDB_Cols+TblTimeCPAReport' is not a field on the target object which is of type 'DBSchema.HTDB_Cols'.

Comment: So you just want to get all the field names from that class?

Comment: A small style comment: returning such a complex string of operations can make it hard to debug if something goes wrong.  I generally prefer to break it up into its smaller steps so that if any one of the Linq methods doesn't return what I expect I can easily decipher which it is.  The compiler will merge it all back together anyway, but it makes the code more readable and maintainable.

Comment: @MikeParkhill mike , 2nd up vote was me, reason is , I like to keep things , same as you say i shouldn't and it is a good point you said that as if some one does not yet knows how exactly the compiler works you could get worried that you're "over loading" the instructions given to cpu because... (if ...you didn't break it down) it should be faster (less instructions to CPU) in real time which is wrong assumption, so cheers for that comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code was close. There were two issues, both located in the arguments to your linq select method call:

- Your class HTDB_Cols is a non-static class and the string values you are trying to retrieve are instance members. Thus when you are trying to pull instance members out of a class, you have to pass an instance of the class to the FieldInof.GetValue method.  In my code below I create an instance of your class in the variable "instanceOfClass".  You can see this in the documentation for the [FieldInfo class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue.aspx)
- The value returned from FieldInfo.GetValue is an object.  You have to explicitly cast it to a string using the ToString method or the (string) cast.

With these two changes your method works.  A listing is as follows:

```
public class GetClassFields
{
    public static List<string> AsList(string tbl)
    {
        var instanceOfClass = new HTDB_Cols();
        return typeof(HTDB_Cols).GetNestedTypes()
                                .First(t => String.Compare(t.Name, tbl, true) == 0)
                                .GetFields()
                                .Select(f => f.GetValue(instanceOfClass).ToString())
                                .ToList<String>();
    }
}
```

You can call this function as follows:

```
var fields = GetClassFields.AsList("TblCustomers");
```

which returns the desired information:

[image]

Comment: this is so kind of you , the best full in depth answer i have ever got... cheers !

Comment: @sorry i had an exeption cause i tried it on some other class , another table , as i was still in tests stage one of them table classes , was holding strings as opposed to const string - threw this as i have update my post, can i understand why did it happen ? in strings case and not on const strings ?

Comment: if you will Omit const flag in your test . you will get what i was getting before I've fixed the second class ... by changing it to the way it supposed to be - `const string somecolumn = "sumcolumn"`. 
is there a simple explenation on this ?

Comment: I omitted the const flag and things still work fine in my example. I can't tell exactly what the issue is without seeing the code, but your error message says that you are passing in a DBSchema.HTDB_Cols+TblTimeCPAReport object instead of a DBSchema.HTDB_Cols or visa-versa.  If you switch the type of the object you are passing in to the other type that should correct it.

Comment: i will inform you on this as i really need to know (although i dont't need any of these classes to hold strings that could be overwriten so they must be readonly or const) **but** my quest is after the concept of system reflection and decleration modifier no less than getting this project done , i am openning a new question so that i will inform you on, shouldn't take more than 10 min' from this comment , you're welcome there

Comment: Sure, I'll be happy to take a look at in the morning (i'm off to bed now). I'll try and remember to look for it.  Or better yet, post the URL in the comments here and I'll see it see it for sure.